# How to Push some data from Database to asp.net webform?

Tags: asp.net

I want to push some thing (like Notification) to user's page, i tried a function that search database and then DB had new notification, it showed the Notification to us, but it was a bad way, someone know how i can do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Comet or SignalR. This is a  [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891053.aspx) to explain how use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Client side side based code, so use ajax and java script to that...

Comment: Is there any way to use serverside function?